# Flutter iOS App on an iOS Simulator running on an M1 Mac

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, apple-m1

Is there an issue with Flutter iOS apps on an iOS simulator (iPhone 12 Pro Max) running on an M1 Mac with Big Sur 11.2.2 and Flutter 1.22.6 ?

You see, my Flutter iOS app (using multiple Flutter plugins) was developed on an Intel-based Mac running Catalina (10.15.7) and Flutter 1.22.5 and it works,  but when I moved to an M1 based Mac running Big Sur and Flutter 1.22.6, I’m having the  Cocoapod’s error:

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile.
```

Note that on this M1 mac, 'flutter doctor' is successful and I can create the Flutter test app and run it on an iOS simulator so I think its setup properly.

I have also tried the solutions suggested with past posts having this symptom to no avail. I have tried the following:

1- I uncommented the line 'platform :ios, '9.0'' in my pods file.

2- I ran the following CLI commands in the terminal:

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
cd ios
pod install
cd ..
flutter build ios
```

The result of trying both suggestions above is the same 'Error running pod install' error with no other error messages mentioned.

The only thing I can think of at this point is that there is a problem with the Flutter plugins I am using when running in an iOS simulator on an M1. Again, these plugins work on an Intel-based Mac running Catalina. If so, unfortunately, the error doesn’t tell me which one. The plugins that I use are:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  provider: ^4.1.3
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+1
  googleapis: ^0.56.1
  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.12
  http: ^0.12.2
  url_launcher: ^5.7.2
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.5
  tuple: ^1.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+12
  intl: ^0.16.1
  fraction: ^1.2.1
  archive: ^2.0.13
  path_provider: ^1.6.24
  path: ^1.7.0
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
```

All help / suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running it on a physical device? the error happening so far is at the build level, and still hasn't reached rendering or M1 issues, if any.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad, I haven't tried running it on a physical device on an M1. I have tried tried running it on a physical device, both iOS and Android, on an Intel-based Mac running Catalina and it works fine. 

I will try this though on an M1 once I find my iPhone. As for Android devices, my VSCODE doesn't seem to recognize the device which is another issue I have to address.

Comment: Did you download the android SDK, even though you're on Mac, the SDK is needed because it contains the ADB manager, needed for android debugging. I ran into an issue yesterday on bigSur, but not M1, simulator didn't support running a release build. Did you run pod install from within the iOS folder? Not just the parent project folder? try to cd into ios or `ios/runner`.

Comment: Thanks, Huthalfa. I'm now in the process of downloading Android Studio  so that I can run it on an Android device to see if that will be possible.

Comment: You're most welcome, do keep us updated, im interested personally. Also, if the problem is in a dependency, pod install will be sure to annoy you with it, but it seems like that something else is going on in your environment that's not reaching that level yet either

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad, sorry for late reply. Pursuing the running on a real android device route, I was able to build the app-debug.apk but during the installation on the device, I'm getting bizzare java runtime errors. More specifically:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.joselitope.myrecipes/com.example.myrecipes.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myrecipes.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[...

Researching solutions to this error, I'm supposed to update my MainActivity in some Kotlin file. Weird.

Comment: @HuthaifaMuayyad, so after modifying that Kotlin file (ie- MainActivity.kt), my app was able to run on a read android device. Ill go back to my  original iOS issue shortly after I celebrate this small victory. I am really puzzled at these weird errors I'm having to face with my move to M1. At the very least, it is highlighting how I've got to up my game when it comes to native Android and iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

## It's not yet supported (Coming in [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/85059))

Flutter has disabled running on simulators running on ARM architecture. They've done this because a flutter dependency (iOS engine Flutter.framework) didn't have arm64 *slices*. There is an open pull request to add support for iOS simulator on M1 macs (arm64): https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/85059

I initially tried to get this working for myself, but the issue is `Generated.xcconfig` contains code which disables arm64 architecture for the simulator, and this file is generated by Flutter internally. Once you manually change this, it still fails. If you tried to build with Xcode, you might get this error message during the linking process:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ClassName
```

*and lots more*. I'd recommend building with Xcode if you don't see enough logs or information to debug the build process.

---

## `Automatically assigning platform` is not an error

`Automatically assigning platform iOS` is not actually an error, it's just telling you its defaulted to iOS platform. It then failed, so in this case, you should've provided more error information.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue.

**Update iOS version to 10.0 in the podfile.**

It worked for me.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I already changed the version to 14.1 to no avail. I also tried it to 10.0 as per your recommendation also to no avail. I'm starting to think I may have to comment out each of my dependencies to see if the dratted 'Error running pod install' error will disappear.

Comment: Have you uncommented that line ?

Comment: not yet. Instead, I'm pursuing the route of trying to run the app in an Android device first. With the route, I was able to build the apk, but when deploying, I'm getting weird ass java runtime exceptions that I've never gotten before in my 2 years of Flutter development. Stay tuned...